# A question related to a NPN transistor having a DC bias

Tags: transistors, bjt, ltspice, npn, bias

[image]

β = current gain

I made the circuit of the above picture with LTspice.

[image]

[image]

(A graph of Vce)

[image]

(A graph of Vbe)

And I was able to get 4.2966V for the value of Vce and 0.6543V for the value of Vbe.

However, when I solved it by hand, the value of Vce was very different.

[image]

**Watch, please**

I translated Korean to English, as follows:

**Korean(English)**

e.g. 등가회로(Equivalent circuit)

As you can see, the value of Vce solved by hand is 2.9181V.

I really don't understand. How can the error of Vce value occur so big?

Did I design the LTspice wrong? Or, did I solve it wrong?

Please, help me.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The KVL equation \$-10 + 7\,[\text k\Omega]\cdot1\,[\text{mA}] + V_{CE}\$ neglects the voltage drop across the current source I1, and that loop cannot be easily solved with KVL alone, because we don't have an equation that tells us the voltage across a current source.

Instead, you know that \$\beta = 100\$ so the base current is \$I_B = 10\,[\mu\text{A}]\$. You can instead solve KVL around this loop:

[image]

We can get \$-10\,[\mu\text{A}]\cdot60\,[\text k\Omega] - V_{BE} + V_{CE} + 7\,[\text k\Omega]\cdot1.01\,[\text{mA}] - 10 = 0\$. When we solve, we get around 4.3 V for Vce which agrees with LT Spice.

In closer detail, the above is equivalent to applying the same step by step logic:

- The base is at -600 mV because of a voltage drop of \$R_B\cdot I_B\$.
- The emitter is at -1.3 V because it's one \$V_{BE}\$ drop below the base.
- The collector current is \$1\,[\text{mA}] \cdot (1 + \beta)\$ so the voltage drop across \$R_C\$ is 7.07 V.
- This makes the collector voltage 2.93 V.
- If emitter is at -1.3 V and collector is at 2.93 V, \$V_{CE}\$ is  4.23 V.
- The error between this result and LT Spice probably arises because we assumed a fixed value for \$V_{BE}\$.

Edit to address comment:

In order to get a Vbe, you need to know a transistor parameter called Saturation Current (\$I_S\$) and then solve the equation \$I_E = I_S( e^{\frac{V_{BE}}{V_T}} - 1)\$. \$V_T\$ is proportional to temperature and is approximately 26 mV at room temperature.

Unfortunately this behavior is really sensitive to temperature and manufacturing variations, so it's hard to always get exact values for Vbe. 0.6 or 0.7 is a good estimate to start. You will find that many circuits use techniques like degeneration and feedback to make them less sensitive to these effects so that the exact saturation current or collector current isn't as important to get exactly right. Also, there are many circuits that have two transistors where we don't care about the actual value of Vbe, only that it's the same for both. In that case there are manufacturing techniques that help ensure this matching.

Comment: I've been trying to solve this problem for almost three hours. But I can't, because I thought KVL could be applied to this circuit. Now, thanks to you, I realized what is wrong and what I did wrong. Thank you so much my hero. I don't know what I would do without you.

Comment: @user299980 Not a problem, I'm very happy to help and am glad that this answer was instructive.

Comment: I'm sorry but, could I get an extra explanation on how to get a VBE? I well understanded everything else, but I can't understand how to get VBE.

Comment: @user299980 I added the answer directly to my answer since it was too long for a comment.

Comment: Thank you very much for always answering my questions passionately. It hasn't been long since I learned electronic engineering, so it's very hard. However, I am really happy to be able to study easily thanks to stackexchange friends like you. I want to reiterate how grateful I am.